# yarn dependency, nodejs, is removed during installation of yarn, and vice versa?

Tags: node.js, debian, yarnpkg

Trying to install a package with yarn, but I get and error saying I need nodejs, but installing nodejs removes yarn.  Likewise, when I install yarn, nodejs is removed.  What am I missing?

```
$ yarn install some-package
Yarn requires Node.js 4.0 or higher to be installed.

$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
...
...
$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gyp libc-ares-dev libjs-node-uuid libv8-3.14-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  yarn
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nodejs
...

$ sudo apt-get install yarn
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gyp libc-ares-dev libjs-node-uuid libv8-3.14-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  nodejs
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  yarn
...
```

Answer (score 17):

I ran into this issue while attempting to install Yarn and NodeJS on WSL. Here are the steps I took to get it working:

```
apt-get remove node
apt-get remove yarn

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs

curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
```

Answer (score 2):

Package `nodejs` can be very old in your distribution, better install from the [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) site.

Once you have a new version of node.js, you can just `npm install -g yarn` to install yarn, or any other method you prefer.

Comment: The Yarn team [recommend against installing via NPM if possible](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#alternatives-tab) - you're better off following [the instructions on their website](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#linux-tab).

Comment: @JoeClay Yes, I know, but the OP cannot install by doing the "recommended way". Note that I said he can try to install via npm or any other method he/she prefer (after fixing the issue with old version of node)

Comment: I don't think they are fully following the recommended way, though? They seem to be trying to get both Node and Yarn from the NodeSource repository, while the instructions say to get Node from NodeSource and Yarn from their own repo (`https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/`). Perhaps they just left that part out of the question, though.